# RAdwords Error in 1:ncol(data) : argument of length 0

Tags: r, google-ads-api

Using RAdwords, I can connect and get a token - list reports and list metrics.  But when I try to pull data i get the error below the code - thanks for the help!

```
body <- statement(select=c('KeywordText','Clicks','Cost','Ctr'),
report="KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
where="Clicks > 100",
start="20150101",
end="20150301")

data <- getData(clientCustomerId='949-xxx-xxxx', google_auth=google_auth,
statement=body, transformation = TRUE)
```

e* upload completely sent off: 130 out of 130 bytes
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Content-Type: text/xml
 Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 18:28:30 GMT
 Expires: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 18:28:30 GMT
 Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 Server: GSE
 Accept-Ranges: none
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

- Connection #0 to host adwords.google.com left intact
  Error in 1:ncol(data) : argument of length 0

Answer (score 2):

Update:
There is an update of the package on my github repository which might solve your problem:
https://github.com/jburkhardt/RAdwords
Could you please reinstall the package from github and see if your bug gets fixed?

---

Austin, referring to the R output you sent me per mail, your problem is:

```
> data <- getData(clientCustomerId='xxx-xxx-xxxx', google_auth=google_auth, statement=body) 
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
```

Please make sure that you use the Adwords Account Id. The MCC Id will not work!

---

This is not an error or bug of the RAdwords package per se. The problem rather has something to do with the curl settings on your system.

See here for similiar problems:
[Curl Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093467/curl-hostname-was-not-found-in-dns-cache-error)
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175433

Comment: When I run this from my VM (which doesn't have cURL at all since this seems to use RCurl) and I am getting the same issue from my mac and windows VM?  All of my R installed packages are built for 3.1?

Comment: Please make sure that you use the Adwords Account Id. The MCC Id will not work!