# Google Oauth2 authentication takes about 15 seconds

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-php-sdk

I am using [google-php-api](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) for authentication.

this takes most of the time just under 6 seconds,
`$client->authenticate($code);`

this takes most of the time about 3 seconds,
`$token = $client->getAccessToken();`

this takes most of the time just under 6 seconds too.
`$client->$data = $client->verifyIdToken($tokens->id_token)`

Any idea why, or is it normal?

Comment: it is if you have a slow connection, it takes time for the server to respond to your request.  That doesn't look to bad to me.

Comment: @daimto cant be internet connection, server on whick it's running is connected to 100 MB/s line ping on google servers is always under 40 ms.

Comment: You could make a script that does it without the client library if it's faster you can take your results to the team behind the client library for assistance. I still don't think that is to bad for times

Comment: @daimto ok thanks we originaly used the api without google-php client, I thought it would be better with using it.

Comment: Not always I have heard the term blotted used when referring to client libraries in the past.

Comment: me too!
about 5 second for GetOrRefreshAccessToken
about 5 secondo for __soapCall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forceing ipv4 hepled

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: Great! Response time improved from ~6 seconds to ~0.5 seconds

Comment: In newer version it should be possible to set it by some function so you don't have manually add the code.

Comment: THanks! If someone encounters issues like: "Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE"
You need to install php-curl and restart your webserver.
For example, on debian with apache2:

`apt-get update;
apt-get install php-curl;
systemctl restart apache2;`

Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The same for me.
The problem was cURL that generate the error: Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache.

Someone here [Curl Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093467/curl-hostname-was-not-found-in-dns-cache-error) say that the issue is the cURL version

--------EDIT--------

I added to /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

first it was only

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

...and all is very fast

Comment: Yes @gianluca-demarinis its seems the issue is caused by [Curl Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093467/curl-hostname-was-not-found-in-dns-cache-error) but adding nameserver 127.0.0.1 to /etc/resolv.conf, btw I found that the conf is created dynamicaly so after restart it wont be there read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf).

Comment: it wont be there only if you have installed Network Manager

Answer (score 1):

For the ones using with Guzzle, supporting @kak3n answer :

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'timeout'           => 3,
    'force_ip_resolve'  => 'v4'
]);

$client->setHttpClient($http);
```

realy worked for me. Before it was around 64 seconds and now only a couple seconds.

Funny part is time out. It takes as long as time out ??? Try it with a longer value see for your self ;)